# ActiveRecord query for FALSE attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, boolean

I'm not sure what the correct terminology is so my Googling didn't help much.

But anyways, ActiveRecord allows you to search all records with a boolean attribute TRUE with something like this:

```
@current_events = Event.current
```

So all events with attribute "current" equals TRUE is returned.

Is there a nifty ActiveRecord method to return all that is FALSE?  Maybe something like:

```
@outdated_events = Event.not_current
```

?

If not, then I can just use the "where" method.  But I was just curious.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be mistaking ActiveRecord 'named scopes' class methods for a Rails feature. For instance,

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.current
    where current: true
  end
end
```

will create the behavior you describe, but not just calling `Foo.current` without the above. So to create `not_current`, yep, use `where`:

```
def self.not_current
  where current: false
end
```

Comment: Yup, you are right.  I forgot I had created a named scope a while back.  Thanks for correcting me!